# Arabic Text is not being shown while converting from html to pdf using iText#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, wkhtmltopdf

I have successfully converted rtf String into html string which was neccessary step to show formatting along with the text. Well by now, i have converted this html into pdf using Markuponverter liberary- the one i found at codeproject. When i open pdf file, it shows English Text with formatting but when i try to convert the text written in Arabic(or Urdu being its subset), no text is there in pdf file after being converted to pdf. I reckoned that it could be a font rendering problem and have tried changing fonts like ARIALUNI.TTF but nothing happened. So far i have tried this and i am going to write a snippet i am using here so anyone could point at mistakes and suggest some tips.

```
RichTextBox rtbnew = new RichTextBox();
        rtbnew.Rtf = this.rtb.Rtf;
        String abc = this.markupConverter.ConvertRtfToHtml(rtbnew.Rtf);
        MessageBox.Show(abc);
        //rtbnew.Text = this.rtb.Text;
        //string str = rtbnew.Text;
        //TextReader tr = new StringReader(str);
        Document doc = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(@path + "/Doc2.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        //////////////////
        doc.Open();

        //Sample HTML
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.Append(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
             <!DOCTYPE html 
                 PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN""
                ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"">
             <html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"" xml:lang=""en"" lang=""en"">
                <head>
                    <title>Minimal XHTML 1.0 Document with W3C DTD</title>
                </head>
              <body>
" + abc + "  </body></html>");

        //Path to our font
        string arialuniTff = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "ARIALUNI.TTF");
        //Register the font with iTextSharp
        iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.Register(arialuniTff);

        //Create a new stylesheet
        iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet ST = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
        //Set the default body font to our registered font's internal name
        ST.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.FACE, "Arial Unicode MS");
        //Set the default encoding to support Unicode characters
        ST.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.ENCODING, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);

        //Parse our HTML using the stylesheet created above
        List<IElement> list = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(stringBuilder.ToString()), ST);

        //Loop through each element, don't bother wrapping in P tags
        foreach (var element in list)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(element.ToString());
            doc.Add(element);
        }

        doc.Close();
```

This code shows English text with and without formattign but doesn't show Arabic Text not even plain text.

Comment: Using pretty much your exact code and only replacing the RTF part with a string literal I was able to get a PDF that outputs Arabic text. `string abc = "میں اردو نہیں بولتے";` It does appear to be backwards when rendered, however. Does it work for you without the RTF part?

Comment: Chris i tried 3 of the techniques and came up with nothing. First i did: rtbnew.Text= this.rtb.Text;
        String abc = this.markupConverter.ConvertRtfToHtml(rtbnew.Rtf); and this gives me again no text except question marks as ???? and second one i tried was: rtbnew.Text= this.rtb.Text;
        String abc = this.markupConverter.ConvertRtfToHtml(rtbnew.Text); and this gives nothing but a blank page.

Comment: Now in a third case when i tried your simple replacement with a simple string of Urdu phrase assigned to a String abc, it gave me Urdu text in a pdf file but words were broken into literals like for میں, it was م ے ن. I don't know what probably should i do? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question marks instead of characters mean `wkhtmltopdf` cannot find the font with Arabic characters. The most fool-proof solution I've found for this is to [Base64-encode your font](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64encode/), and include it directly in the CSS/style declaration:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Amiri';
    src: url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,<BASE64-ENCODED-DATA>
}
```

EDIT: Step by step instructions:

1. Visit [this site](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64encode/).
2. Upload your font to `Encode binary file`, then press `Encode`. That will encode the file and generate the encoded font. The output will look like a bunch of random characters.
3. Copy the CSS snippet above, and replace `<BASE64-ENCODED-DATA>` with the Base64 output that you got from encoding.
4. Add this CSS snippet to your stylesheet, somewhere near the top. It's important to add this before you refer to `ARIALUNI` font in your CSS code.
5. Now you can declare HTML elements to use this font, as you normally would:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ARIALUNI';
    src: url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,AAEAAAATAQA...
}
body, h1 {
    font-family: 'ARIALUNI', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with this at all and can you please tell me the procedure of converting ARIALUNI.ttf font into base64 font and then embedding it into style.css file?

Comment: Do i need to upload ARIALUNI.ttf file there? I mean i have this as how can i convert it into binary file?

Comment: Do i need to put your above mentioned code snippet in styles.css file? And where to put the encoded data i mean should that be put inside styles.css file? And then i need to refer that css file like st.LoadTagStyle("body", "face", "c:\\documents\\styles.css");

Comment: Yes, upload it to the site as instructed in step 2. Replace `<BASE64-ENCODED-DATA>` in my example with encoded font (what you get from the website). Then add the entire `@font-face` CSS declaration to your `styles.css` file.

Comment: I did as you 'd said but in-vain. Well, it is showing English Text but not Urdu Text and when i open pdf file properties, it shows Helvetica in Font Tab. I don't know why ain't it picking up that style sheet or what?

Comment: My code is: iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.Register(@"fonts\\ARIALUNI_2.ttf","Arial Unicode MS");
            
            StyleSheet st = new StyleSheet();
            
            st.LoadTagStyle("body", "face", "style.css");
            st.LoadTagStyle("body", "encoding", "Identity-H");
            st.LoadTagStyle("body", "leading", "12,0");
            HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(document);
            
            
            List<IElement> p = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(stringReader,st);
foreach (var element in p) {
                document.Add(element);   }

Comment: Kindly if you could convert the ARIALUNI.ttf font into Base64 encoded font and then could send it to me via e-mail? Whta i did befor conversion that instead of uploading ARIALUNI.ttf file, i first converted into .fnt file(after alot of browsing i came at that) using BM Font(because i don't know how to convert .ttf to binary file as website demanded that binary file to be uploaded). My e-mail address is: starshahid.sultan251@gmail.com

Comment: Why are you complicating things? You don't need to convert anything to `.fnt`, just upload the `ttf` font to that website. It will accept the font as it is.